# Display HTML page after servlet is finished

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a Servlet which accept username and password and authenticates it. 
After it is done, I want to display an HTML page.

It is a big *HTML* page so I read that using `writer.println()` was not a good idea.

How do I display the new page?

I tried using **sendRedirect** but that, for some reason, displayed the same page (login page) again.

Please help.

Comment: Forward to a JSP. Never mix Java and HTML.

Comment: What would the JSP page do? Wouldn't it look exactly like the HTML page, since I am not putting in Java code into it?

Comment: Read our [info page on JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info).

Comment: Yes. But you will want to read the session at the top of the JSP to make sure the user is logged in and redirect to a login page if not. With .html you can't check if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `JSP` page contains your HTML, then use `requestDispatcher` to forward the request.

for Example:

if you created a `JSP` page named `MyJSP`, then in login `Servlet` use:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("MyJSP.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I did this. Put the JSP in WebContent folder in Eclipse. It says "The requested resource is not available"!

Comment: Where did you locate your jsp file, what its path??, also what have you tried ?

Comment: If your servlet is like a subfolder down, you might need to reference the JSP with ../, i.e. `request.getRequestDispatcher("../MyJSP.jsp")`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this  lines of code 
  create an html whatever the  name you like  i had created `LoggedIn.html` and 
use this code in your servlet

```
ServletContext context= getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/LoggedIn.html");
rd.forward(request, response);
```